# get iframe from backround page chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension that when you click on the icon, a popup comes up that displays http://html5.grooveshark.com/ and plays music. I want to be able to have it run in the background so the music will play, even after the person clicks away from the popup. If I set my "default_popup" to an HTML file with the code below, it shows Grooveshark, and plays music, but stops playing music after the popup is closed. How do I get it to keep playing music in the background?

Code (Displays Grooveshark.com)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style type="text/css">
        body {
             width: 500px;
             height: 300px;
             }
</style>

<body>


<iframe src="http://html5.grooveshark.com/" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"     scrolling="yes"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either play it from your background page, which is always running, or open a small, borderless window containing the iframe.

Comment: how you play it from the background window? That is what i'm trying to figure out :P

Answer (score 0):

Just create a background.html and place your code in there. You can check that it is playing by setting an autoplay on your source.

Then, you just have to embed your background.html in your popup.html!

So, your call in the popup would basically be:

```
<iframe src="path/to/background.html"></iframe>
```